# Internal structure of a boost::smart_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am trying to establish what data member primitives/objects (beyond the `T*` pointer) the `boost` (or `std` if its easier) `shared_ptr` has, which would be in the same L1 cache line as the `T*` pointer, when the `shared_ptr` is used to access the underlying heap memory?

When I do:

```
sizeof(boost::shared_ptr<int>)
```

and

```
sizeof(boost::shared_ptr<double>)
```

I get the same answer- 8 bytes, but on my system an int is 4 bytes and a double is 8 bytes?

I looked at the boost source code for `shared_ptr`:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

but I couldn't even see the `T*` data member.... so I am not overly sure how a `boost::shared_ptr` looks in terms of data members?

Comment: The link you show is a synopsis, not real code, so it doesn't show internals.  The actual code can be seen here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp, and the two members are `element_type * px;` and `boost::detail::shared_count pn;`

Comment: On 64-bit systems, pointer size should always (?) be 8 bytes regardless of what it's pointing to (except when it's pointing to an array, then `sizeof` returns the size of the type times the length of the array. `double` is 8 bytes as defined by IEEE 754. `int` is usually 4 bytes long, to get a 64-bit integer type you could use `long long` or `std::int64_t` from `<cstdint>`.

Comment: In general, it's probably more efficient to refer to the boost sources that are already on your machine instead of the web pages at www.boost.org (the headers will be there for certain, the sources for any lib file might not, but those account for a very small percentage of boost).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::shared_ptr<>` contains two pointers, one to the object itself and one to the tracker object used for reference counting, proper destruction etc. That means it will be `2 * sizeof(void*)` big.

The structure of the tracker object is of course an implementation detail, but it is a few dozen bytes large (virtual table, pointer to the object, reference count, weak count and some extra flags and whatnot).

If you use `boost::make_shared()` as recommended, both the object itself and the information helding one will be created in one heap block and the pointers will be just a few bytes apart.

Comment: Wouldn't `sizeof(boost::shared_ptr<whatever>)` return 16 then, since a raw pointer on 64-bit systems should be 8 bytes long?

Comment: @MoreAxes: It depends how it was compiled. Apparently it was compiled as 32-bit.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately I don't see any notion about architecture by the OP, but from the reported size 8, I assume it's a 32-bit one.